# Register service from different file in the controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with register the service from one file inside the controller in the other file.

I have main file which is called `"script.js"` and it looks like this:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

  var MainController = function(scope, github, interval, log, anchorScroll, location) {
      //some code which is not important here
  };

  app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", github, "$interval", "$log", "$anchorScroll", "$location", MainController]);
}());
```

There is also a second file called `"github.js"`:

```
(function() {

  var github = function($htpp) {

    var getUser = function(username) {
      //return user data
    };

    var getRepos = function(user) {
      //return repo data
    }

    return {
      getUser: getUser,
      getRepos: getRepos
    };
  };

  var module = angular.module("myApp");
  module.factory("github", github);

}());
```

And it's not working... I have no idea what I'm missing... I'm watching tutorial, but it was prepared on older version of Angular...

Of course, in `.html` file reference to `"script.js"` is before `"github.js"`.

EDIT: 
I was missing the double quotes in the dependency for github and there was misspelling in "github.js" - $htpp instead of $http...

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you get any error?

Comment: `github` has to be in double quotes, `"github"` in dependency.

Comment: Also in github.js the dependency should be `$http` instead of `$htpp`

Comment: Thank you guys! I didn't notice this little spelling... And of course the github should be in double quotes in dependency. 
Great! Thank you :)
Btw, could someone could try to help me with this issue - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44539045/changing-number-format-dynamically-from-dropdown-list) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few typos in your code :

1.`github` dependency has to be in double quotes, `"github"` in dependency, Like:

```
 app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "github", "$interval", "$log", "$anchorScroll", "$location", MainController]);
```

2.As suggestion : In controller, dependecy should be same(missing `$`), Do it like :

```
 var MainController = function($scope, github, $interval, $log, $anchorScroll, $location) {
```

3.In your factory dependency, it should be `$http` (Not htpp)

Comment: About 2nd point... Why it should be with a dollar sign ?? Its working without it... I thought that there I can call it whatever I want to...

Comment: It a suggestion, that it should be same,.